# Filter a List using Dictionary keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to filter a `List` using `Linq Where / Select`, using the value of keys in the `Dictionary` as shown in the program, my current solution has number of limitations.

`Dictionary` refers to user input from UI, so it may contain a collection of values instead of single value for a given key.

Any pointer to help me with a right direction.

```
 public class Business
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }

void Main()
{
    var businessList = new List<Business>
    {
      new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "A"},
      new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "B"},
      new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "C"},
      new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "D"},
      new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "E"},
      new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "F"},
      new Business {ID = 3,NAME = "G"},
      new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "H"},
      new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "I"},
      new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "J"},
      new Business {ID = 5,NAME = "K"},
      new Business {ID = 5,NAME = "L"}
    };

    var filterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      {"ID",3},
      {"NAME","G"}
    };

   Expected Result:
   ID    Name
   3      G

   var filterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      {"ID",new List<int>(){2,3}}
    };

 Expected Result:
   ID    Name
   2      D
   2      E
   2      F
   3      G

Current Solution:

    var result = businessList
                 .Select(x => filterDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(Business).GetProperty("ID").Name) ?
                             x.ID == (int)filterDictionary[typeof(Business).GetProperty("ID").Name] ? x : null : null                            
                       )
                 .Where(x => x!= null)
                 .Select(x => filterDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(Business).GetProperty("NAME").Name) ?
                             x.NAME == (string)filterDictionary[typeof(Business).GetProperty("NAME").Name] ? x : null : null
                       );   
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? the Business objects that have ID = 3 AND Name = G? Or that have ID = 3 OR Name = G? Could the dictionary contain more than two items?

Comment: Result shall be the combination of the values i.e. ID = 3 AND Name = G out here. Yes it can contain keys which have are not part of Business entity in few corner case, but as of Now I would be good to assume that dictionary can only contain valid keys

Comment: But what does it mean in this case to have three or four items in the dictionary? For example, what if the dictionary contains the following: ID = 2, ID = 4, NAME = E? NAME = H?

Comment: @YacoubMassad That would simply mean that post filtering, there can be an empty result, therefore no match available

Comment: So if there are more than one ID in the dictionary that have different values then the result would be empty. The same goes for NAME, right?

Comment: No, that would be the case only when there are no matching records, in the subsequently filtered list, as all values are applied one by one on the subset

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide an example that contains more than two elements in the collection and the expected output for that case?

Comment: Edited, please have a look

Comment: So the first dictionary contains a simple `int` of the value of "ID", but the second one contains a `List<int>` for the value of the "ID". It seems to me that you can only have two items in the dictionary, but the value of the items can contain multiple values.

Comment: yes these are the options, since user would select values, it can be single filter value or multiple as the example shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way to do this would be to the property GetMethod using reflection and caching these to improve performance as reflection can be quite slow. You can also use generics so that it will work with any type. Something like the following may be what you are looking for.

```
private static List<T> FilterList<T>( IEnumerable<T> source, Dictionary<string, object> propertyFilters )
{
    var properties = propertyFilters.Keys.Distinct()
                                            .ToDictionary( x => x, x => typeof ( T ).GetProperty( x ).GetGetMethod() );

    IEnumerable<T> result = source.ToList();
    foreach ( var propertyFilter in propertyFilters )
    {
        if ( properties.ContainsKey( propertyFilter.Key ) )
        {
            result = result.Where( x =>
            {
                var invoke = properties[propertyFilter.Key].Invoke( x, new object[0] );
                if ( propertyFilter.Value is IList )
                {
                     return ( (IList)propertyFilter.Value ).Cast<object>().Any( f =>
                     {
                         return f.Equals( invoke );
                     } );
                }
                return invoke.Equals( propertyFilter.Value );
            } );
        }
    }
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: this works like a breeze, thank you so much, providing all the valid values for multiple combinations

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution:

```
//Calculate valid IDs from the dictionary
List<int> valid_ids =
    filterDictionary
        .Where(x => x.Key == "ID")
        .SelectMany(x =>
        {
            if (x.Value is int)
            {
                return new[] {(int) x.Value};
            }

            return (IEnumerable<int>) x.Value;

        }).ToList();


//Calculate valid NAMEs from the dictionary
List<string> valid_names =
        filterDictionary
        .Where(x => x.Key == "NAME")
        .SelectMany(x =>
        {
            if (x.Value is string)
            {
                return new[] { (string)x.Value };
            }

            return (IEnumerable<string>)x.Value;

        }).ToList();


IEnumerable<Business> query = businessList;

if (valid_ids.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => valid_ids.Contains(x.ID));

if(valid_names.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(x => valid_names.Contains(x.NAME));

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Must agree a very elegant solution, that is pretty easy to understand

Comment: Can you please help me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120664/how-to-group-by-on-2-child-entities-and-get-total-of-both-this-child-entities

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in one row (gives back the expected result):

```
var result = businessList.Where(bl => filterDictionary
             .Count(fd => bl.GetType().GetProperty(fd.Key).GetValue(bl, null) == fd.Value) > 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary can only have unique keys.  Where you have the same key more than once the value of the key must be a collection.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Business> businessList = new List<Business>
            {
              new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "A"},
              new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "B"},
              new Business {ID = 1,NAME = "C"},
              new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "D"},
              new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "E"},
              new Business {ID = 2,NAME = "F"},
              new Business {ID = 3,NAME = "G"},
              new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "H"},
              new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "I"},
              new Business {ID = 4,NAME = "J"},
              new Business {ID = 5,NAME = "K"},
              new Business {ID = 5,NAME = "L"}
            };

            Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = businessList.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.ID, y => y.NAME)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

       }
        public class Business
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public string NAME { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By no means this is a solution, it doesn't provide a solution for the problem statement